# Java - How to Load Classes your Main does'nt know the name from?

Tags: java, class, package, classloader

I would like to have a Method like:

`loadAllClassesOfPackage("com.elementghost.projectname");`

But my main will not be able to know the Classes that should be loaded.
It will only know a package, and from this package, every classes constructor or static block (Both oportunities would be okay), should be loaded.

Is it possible to pass my Main a package, and then in every class in it, will be executed the constructor.

Comment: Have you thought about the fact, that no of the solutions worked for me and I want to hear more ideas?

Comment: And I dont want to find the classes, I want to directly load them, with the solutions on the "duplicate", my question isnt answered.